# Change activity's behavior with checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

So, I'm attempting to change the equations with a checkbox, I am attaching a sample of code to see if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong. With this code, I am simply trying to not make any calculations when the checkbox is checked, and to automatically calculate and populate the other fields when the checkbox is not checked. It works perfectly until I check, uncheck, and recheck the checkbox. I can verify it's status with my textview, but It continues to focus on the textviews when checked or unchecked... Thank you for any help!

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIn);
    final EditText editFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFt);
    final EditText editYd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editYd);
    final TextView checkBoxChecked = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChecked);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                checkBoxChecked.setText("Check Box Checked");

            } else {
                checkBoxChecked.setText("Check Box NOT Checked!");
                editIn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (editIn.hasFocus()) {

                            try {
                                double in = Double.valueOf(editIn.getText().toString());
                                double ft = in / 12;
                                double yd = in / 36;
                                editFt.setText(String.format("%.2f", (ft)));
                                editYd.setText(String.format("%.2f", (yd)));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                editFt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (editFt.hasFocus()) {
                            try {
                                double ft = Double.valueOf(editFt.getText().toString());
                                double in = ft * 12;
                                double yd = ft / 3;
                                editIn.setText(String.format("%.2f", (in)));
                                editYd.setText(String.format("%.2f", (yd)));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                editYd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if (editYd.hasFocus()) {
                            try {
                                double yd = Double.valueOf(editYd.getText().toString());
                                double in = yd * 36;
                                double ft = yd * 3;
                                editIn.setText(String.format("%.2f", (in)));
                                editFt.setText(String.format("%.2f", (ft)));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a setOnCheckedChangeListener, not a onCLickListener.  You also need to move the equation within OnTextChanged

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIn);
    final EditText editFt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFt);
    final EditText editYd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editYd);
    final TextView checkBoxChecked = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxChecked);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
     checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    checkBoxChecked.setText("Check Box Checked");
                  editIn.setText("");
                  editIn.setEnabled(false);
                  editIn.setFocusable(false);
                  editFt.setText("");
                  editFt.setEnabled(false);
                  editFt.setFocusable(false);
                  editYd.setText("");
                  editYd.setEnabled(false);
                  editYd.setFocusable(false);
                } else {
                 editIn.setEnabled(true);
                 editIn.setFocusable(true);
                 editFt.setEnabled(true);
                 editFt.setFocusable(true);
                 editYd.setEnabled(true);
                 editYd.setFocusable(true);
                 checkBoxChecked.setText("Check Box NOT Checked!");

                  editIn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                       try {
                            double in = Double.valueOf(editIn.getText().toString());
                            double ft = in / 12;
                            double yd = in / 36;
                            editFt.setText(String.format("%.2f", (ft)));
                            editYd.setText(String.format("%.2f", (yd)));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
                editFt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                     try {
                            double ft = Double.valueOf(editFt.getText().toString());
                            double in = ft * 12;
                            double yd = ft / 3;
                            editIn.setText(String.format("%.2f", (in)));
                            editYd.setText(String.format("%.2f", (yd)));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
                editYd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                    try {
                                double yd = Double.valueOf(editYd.getText().toString());
                                double in = yd * 36;
                                double ft = yd * 3;
                                editIn.setText(String.format("%.2f", (in)));
                                editFt.setText(String.format("%.2f", (ft)));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
                }
            }
        });


}
```

**UPDATE** Try this and let me know it is displaying the toast with each check and uncheck

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not-Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yessir, I had tried that before, but I copied and pasted your code, and it unfortunately had the same result. If you try it, it seems to work, until you cycle the checkbox, then it seems to retain focus on the other edittexts. Thank you very much for your response! I hope you can help me resolve this...

Comment: I will try my best.  Tell me exactly what you want to happen when you check and unchecked the checkbox

Comment: I would like that when I check the box that nothing happens when I input into the fields, then later I can add a method to that. Right now, it still calculates after I cycle the checkbox

Comment: So you want the editText's not to do anything if the check box is checked.

Comment: Correct, I  will add another method later

Comment: Sorry bud, same thing, just now I'm not able to type in the edit texts